# How to make a gap between two DIV within the same column

Tags: html, css

I have two paragraphs. The two paragraphs are located in the same column. Now my question is I need to make the two paragraphs in two separate boxes, down each other. In other words, gap between two boxes coming down each other.

HTML Code

```
    <div class="sidebar">

                <div class="box1">
                    <p> 
                    Text is here
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="box2">
                    <p> 
                    Text is here 
                    </p>
                </div>

     </div>
```

My CSS Code is

```
.sidebar {
    background: red;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0 7px 0 7px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.box1 {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.box2 {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Like here
[image]

Comment: Not really following what you want but can you not just add a margin to the boxes?

Comment: Don't really understand "gap between two boxes coming down each other"

Comment: @Scott I mean box1 first then box2 under it, but it should be a gap between them

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please pay attention to the comments after the 2 lines.

```
.box1 {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 100px; /* SIMPLY SET THIS PROPERTY AS MUCH AS YOU WANT. This changes the space below box1 */
    text-align: justify;
}

.box2 {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 100px; /* OR ADD THIS LINE AND SET YOUR PROPER SPACE as the space above box2 */
}
```

Comment: Or, better yet: `.box { display: block; padding: 10px; text-align: justify; margin: 100px 0; }`

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want the two boxes in the sidebar to be next to each other horizontally, so something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ed_melly/Mw677/)? That uses `inline-block`, or you could achieve the same thing by floating the boxes.

*EDIT* - I've amended the above fiddle to do what I think you want, though your question could really do with being clearer. Similar to @balexandre's answer, though I've used `:nth-child(odd)` instead. Both will work, or if support for older browsers is important you'll have to stick with another helper class.

Comment: @HTMLMan Your comment and your question are inconsistent! Should the two divs be placed horizontally or vertically?

Comment: @smhnaji i do an image for what i need to do

Comment: @HTMLMan - what should the height of the margin be? Are you trying to position the second box at the bottom of a sidebar with a specific height?

Comment: @HTMLMan Dear friend, even increasing the `margin-bottom` in `.box1`'s CSS could simply increase the spaces between the two `div`s. Or you could set a `margin-top` property in `.box2`'s CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the [first-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) selector

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="box">
        <p> 
            Text is here
         </p>
     </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p> 
            Text is here
         </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

and in CSS

```
.box {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.box:first-child {
    margin-top: none;
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/ozarot/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: will it should be totally separated. it should like that 
Red background Para1 
 background of the sidebar
Red background para2

Answer (score 1):

> you can use $nbsp; for a single space, if you like 
>   **just using single allows you single space instead of using creating own class**

```
    <div id="bulkOptionContainer" class="col-xs-4">
        <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
            <option value="">Select Options</option>
            <option value="">Published</option>
            <option value="">Draft</option>
            <option value="">Delete</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success " value="Apply">
         &nbsp;
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="add_posts.php">Add post</a>

    </div>


</form>
```

[CLICK ON IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qru6H.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
#firstDropContainer{
float: left; 
width: 40%; 
margin-right: 1.5em; 

}

#secondDropContainer{
float: left; 
width: 40%;
margin-bottom: 1em;
}



<div id="mainDrop">
    <div id="firstDropContainer"></div>
    <div id="secondDropContainer"></div>
</div>

Note: Adjust the width of the divs based on your req.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this was an old answer, but i would like to share my simple solution.

give `style="margin-top:5px"`

```
<div style="margin-top:5px">
  div 1
</div>
<div style="margin-top:5px">
  div2 elements
</div>
```

div3 elements